# My .push() command is saying that my nested object is not assignable

Tags: typescript

So I'm trying to make an array using objects of objects. But I want the objects to be able to vary quite dramatically within the "details". Example starting list:

```
shoppingList = [
  {
    name: "fish",
    quantity: "2",
    details: {
      type: "cod",
      weightEach: "100g",
    },
  },
  {
    name: "coffee mugs",
    quantity: "6",
    details: {
      color: "white",
    },
  },
]
```

Then I have a function that's supposed to add another blank item to the list for the user to fill details out for later

```
addItem(){
  this.shoppingList.push({
    name: "default value here",
    quantity: "1",
    details: {
    },
  })
}
```

But I get an error saying that the type '{}' is not assignable to type '{ type: string; weightEach: string; color: string; }'.

Is there some other way of storing and adding objects to a list with drastically varying metadata?
btw, if this sounds like a basic beginner question, you're probably right. Just getting on my feet with angular right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add an `interface` for shopping list. The interface can be created using `ng g i shoppingList` also you need to add it like below.

```
export interface shoppingList  {
    name: string,
    quantity: string,
    details: {
      type?: string,
      weightEach?: string,
    },
  },
```

Please note the `?` added to the property name, this will tell typescript that its optional paramater, now `details` will accept `{}`.

```
shoppingList: ShoppingList = [
  {
    name: "fish",
    quantity: "2",
    details: {
      type: "cod",
      weightEach: "100g",
    },
  },
  {
    name: "coffee mugs",
    quantity: "6",
    details: {
      color: "white",
    },
  },
]
```

Comment: Working well so far. I'm still adding features, so we'll see how it integrates. One small thing, I had to write it as shippingList: ShoppingList[] = [ ... ] Without the brackets right after "ShoppingList" it wouldn't compile properly